# Limit the number of records in table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to limit the number of records a table can hold in rails. If I have a notifications table, how can I make it work to hold only 50 records at a time. So, if a new record is added the first one is deleted and the new one is saved as the 50th.

Is there any cool rails method to do this automatically or do I have to implement it manually in my model when I'm creating a new notification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's quite simple to implement on own.

```
 Notification.first.destroy if Notification.count > 50
```

use it in `after_commit` callback or whatever cb is best

Comment: What a great and elegant solution! Thanks